# Use UpdatePanel in SharePoint 2010

Tags: ajax, sharepoint-2010, reference, updatepanel

In msdn i found this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650218.aspx
but I don't know where to find reference to Microsoft.Practices.SPG.AJAXSupport.dll
Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u downloaded the ajax tools??
if yes thn just add tht tools in web.cnfig in safe control assemblies. and start using it in your page